# Error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference (Tesseract)

Tags: java, react-native, tesseract

I have problem with react-native-tesseract-ocr I know the problem is related to LANG_ENGLISH property, I tried to put "eng" instead but nothing changed. when I remove it error is gone but the result is nonsense. Here the full error and piece of code:

```
OCR Error:  Error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
    at Object.promiseMethodWrapper [as recognize] (D:\Uni\React-Native\tesseract\TextRecognition\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:103)
    at _callee$ (VM5 src\Screens\Camera.bundle:105)
    at tryCatch (D:\Uni\React-Native\tesseract\TextRecognition\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (D:\Uni\React-Native\tesseract\TextRecognition\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293)
    at Generator.next (D:\Uni\React-Native\tesseract\TextRecognition\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:118)
    at tryCatch (D:\Uni\React-Native\tesseract\TextRecognition\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63)
    at invoke (D:\Uni\React-Native\tesseract\TextRecognition\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:154)
    at D:\Uni\React-Native\tesseract\TextRecognition\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:164
    at tryCallOne (D:\Uni\React-Native\tesseract\TextRecognition\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37)
    at D:\Uni\React-Native\tesseract\TextRecognition\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123
```

here is how I use it :

```
RNTesseractOcr.recognize(path,  LANG_ENGLISH   , tessOptions)
 .then((result) => {
  console.log("OCR Result: ", result);
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try RNTesseractOcr.recognize(path, 'LANG_ENGLISH', tessOptions) with LANG_ENGLISH inside quotes such as 'LANG_ENGLISH'

Comment: it returns nonsense result like this : OCR Result:  \ its“.
3 {ﬁgyg
ﬁes;

5” >
rs/ "
A/fé
4mA

Comment: well it's a different problem. What are you trying to recognize? Does the path include an image with english characters? Or may be even tesseract can not recognize anything? You must explain what you're trying to recognize and how

Comment: i'm just trying to recognize some text behind my book or even characters on my keyboard both written in English. I use react-native-camera for taking the picture and pass the path to tesseract .                                                                                        const data = await myCamera.takePictureAsync({});                                                     const path = data.uri.replace('file://', '');                                                                                RNTesseractOcr.recognize(path,  'LANG_ENGLISH'   , tessOptions)

Comment: Check out https://github.com/jonathanpalma/react-native-tesseract-ocr/blob/master/example/App.js

Comment: i used it and it worked !  the problem was maybe the react-native-camera not sure. You saved my life thanks !

Comment: also using 'LANG_ENGLISH'